# Hide current tab and display the next tab based on href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide the current tab which is displayed and fadein the new tab based on its href using jquery...

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="leader">
    <ul id="llist">
         <li class="t current"><a href="#solutions"><span>sage solutions</span></a></li>
         <li class="m"><a href="#management"><span>credit mangement solutions</span></a></li>
         <li class="b"><a href="#thirdparty"><span>third party additions</span></a></li>
    </ul>

                <div id="lcontent">
                    <div id="solutions" class="tab">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        Description
                    </div>                  
                    <div id="management" class="tab">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        Description
                    </div>
                    <div id="thirdparty" class="tab">
                        <h2>Title</h2>
                        Description
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

And the JQUERY (which also slides an image to the tab which is selected)

```
$('#leader #llist li').click(function() {
    $('#leader #llist li').removeClass('current');
var thisTop = $(this).offset().top;
$('.pointer').animate( {'top': thisTop} );
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $('.tab').fadeOut();
```

});

The current tabs dont currently fadeout or fadein when the links in the list are clicked...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am trying to fade out the tabs when the user clicks one of the links based on its ID (hence use of #href) which i thought would be the best way to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you are looking for.

http://jsbin.com/iceli4/edit

Hope this gets you started.

Bob